# Detecting Which 3-manifolds are Orientation Double Covers

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

> > Given a 3-manifold $M$, what algebraic-topological methods can one use to detect or obstruct whether or not it is an orientation double cover?

Some basic things one can quickly observe about orientation double covers $M$ include:

1) M admits a free, orientation reversing, involutive homeomorphism

2) By the Lefshetz fixed point theorem, if $\phi$ is the homeomorphism from 1), one has $$ 1  - tr(\phi_{*}|_{H_{1}}) + tr(\phi_{*}|_{H_{2}}) + 1 =0$$
This implies for example that rational homology 3-spheres don't arise as orientation double covers, and that orientation double covers have infinite $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$. Perhaps it has other implications I don't see?

Are there other basic facts or results which allow you to look at algebraic-topological data associated to $M$ to obstruct it being such a cover?

Comment: What is your proof of 1)? I worry about that statement because it seems backwards to me. If there exists an orientation double covering map $f : M \to N$ then $f_* : \pi_1 M \to \pi_1 N$ is an isomorphism onto an index two subgroup of $\pi_1 N$. So instead of 1) one could say that $\pi_1(M)$ has a supergroup of index 2, i.e. $\pi_1(M)$ is embeddable as an index 2 subgroup of some other group (which is saying nothing useful because *every* group has a supergroup of index 2).

Comment: Whoops, you are certainly correct, that was patently backwards! I agree and I've retracted that comment, but my question still stands.